# The visualiser for QR Code Tracking within HoloLens 2 doesn't seem to track* the QR code in real time. QR Code Visualiser doesn't track QR code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, qr-code, hololens

Would appreciate it if someone could help me with this problem -

Problem Description-
I know for a fact that it scans as the information of the QR code is displayed along with the time stamp (which constantly updates in real time when I move the QR code around in real time). [image]

*the axis is supposed to follow the QR code held in my hand(not shown), but it doesn't*

```
using UnityEngine;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities;

#if MIXED_REALITY_OPENXR
using Microsoft.MixedReality.OpenXR;
#else
using QRTracking.WindowsMR;
#endif

namespace QRTracking
{
    public class SpatialGraphNodeTracker : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private System.Guid _id;
        private SpatialGraphNode node;

        public System.Guid Id
        {
            get => _id;

            set
            {
                if (_id != value)
                {
                    _id = value;
                    InitializeSpatialGraphNode(force: true);
                }
            }
        }

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start()
        {
            InitializeSpatialGraphNode();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            InitializeSpatialGraphNode();
            if (node != null && node.TryLocate(FrameTime.OnUpdate, out Pose pose))
            {
                // If there is a parent to the camera that means we are using teleport and we should not apply the teleport
                // to these objects so apply the inverse
                if (CameraCache.Main.transform.parent != null)
                {
                    pose = pose.GetTransformedBy(CameraCache.Main.transform.parent);
                }

                gameObject.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(pose.position, pose.rotation);
                //Debug.Log("Id= " + id + " QRPose = " +  pose.position.ToString("F7") + " QRRot = "  +  pose.rotation.ToString("F7"));
            }
        }

        private void InitializeSpatialGraphNode(bool force = false)
        {
            if (node == null || force)
            {
                node = (Id != System.Guid.Empty) ? SpatialGraphNode.FromStaticNodeId(Id) : null;
                Debug.Log("Initialize SpatialGraphNode Id= " + Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA6ADE5E5C (KernelBase.dll) in QRBeginning.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80070057 : 'Ãŗġŭmзήτ ςαŋиóŧ ьє йµĺℓ.'.
analog\input\mirage\publicapi\spatialcoordinatesystembase.cpp(36)\Windows.Mirage.dll!00007FFA60752DC4: (caller: 00007FFA31F84DD0) ReturnHr(14551) tid(5cc) 80070057 The parameter is incorrect.
    Msg:[target]
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA6ADE5E5C in QRBeginning.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Il2CppExceptionWrapper at memory location 0x0000005E27EFD1B0.
ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.
Ãŗġŭmзήτ ςαŋиóŧ ьє йµĺℓ.
  at Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem.TryGetTransformTo (Windows.Perception.Spatial.SpatialCoordinateSystem target) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at QRTracking.WindowsMR.SpatialGraphNode.TryLocate (QRTracking.WindowsMR.FrameTime frameTime, UnityEngine.Pose& pose) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at QRTracking.SpatialGraphNodeTracker.Update () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
Initialize SpatialGraphNode Id= 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
QRTracking.SpatialGraphNodeTracker:InitializeSpatialGraphNode(Boolean)
QRTracking.SpatialGraphNodeTracker:Update()
```

It has been bugging me for about a week now, these are some of the things i have tried. -
*// reduced the error by assigning id = gameObject.GetComponent().qrCode.SpatialGraphNodeId*

*// "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is the next error*

*// assuming that my assignment is wrong / qr code reading functionality also went down*

*// went back to original*

*// used SpatialGraphNodeTracker.cs instead of SpatialGraphCoordinateSystem.cs*

Followed this guide -

https://codeholo.com/2021/03/27/qrcode-tracking-with-hololens-2-xr-sdk-and-mrtk-v2-5/

Found this the most verbose helpful guide for what I am doing.

**- P.S Does anyone know why the documentation for HoloLens 2 development is so byzantine. I am sure there is something i am not seeing...**

What do you guys use?

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilt from source (everything worked as expected) -
https://github.com/NSudharsan/HoloLensExamples/tree/master/QRCodeXRSDK